# Deploying JAR in JBOSS

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Im having a jar file(for java classes) with some associated files of my project.Its bacially a client/server based application,but not web based.How can I run this program in a machine(24*7)?
How can i deploy it in any application server?

Comment: No.  How would JBoss know what to do with it?

Comment: actually thats a executable jar file,just i want to deploy it.

Comment: No, JBoss won't run arbitrary applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You don't need JBoss or any other application server**. Just start it:

```
java -jar yourfile.jar
```

and it will run 24/7. To start it in the background, add " &" to it. If you look for ways to start it automatically, with the system your could use init.d (if on unix/linux).

**If you want to use an application server anyway**, just wrap your jar in a war file and deploy it. This can be done using [Ant's War Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html) or maybe directly from your IDE.